# Referencing a CSS class only within a specific element only

Tags: html, css

I have defined this:

```
.grade a{
    color: white;
}
```

It works. too well..

I have an html like so

```
<li class="grade">
   <a><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i></a>
      My Text 
</li>
```

The bootsrap i star element is painted white. And I don't want it to.

How can I only specify element with a of class .grade

```
<a class="grade"> Text here should be white </a>
```

and not other elements?

Comment: add another rule for `.grade a{color: red}`

Comment: Have you tried `.grade {color: white}` ?

Comment: do you want exactly? is not clear you question.

Comment: @MohammadUsman, yes. Then It doesn't "catch" the "Text here should be white" and instead, it's something else

Comment: It should work unless some other styles are overriding this rule. It would be easy for us if you could create some working example of Fiddle.

Comment: @ehsan , edited the question "The bootsrap i star element is painted white. And I don't want it to."

Comment: You can override color for star by overriding its color as `.grade .fa-star {color: blue;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is, you are selecting any `a` element which is a descendant of an element with the class `grade`.

To specify an `a` element that has the `grade` class itself, change your selector to:

```
a.grade
```

```css
a.grade {
  color: red;
}

.grade a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li class="grade">
   <a><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw">Text within an &lt;a&gt; descendant of .grade</i></a><br>
      Text outside of &lt;a&gt; element
</li>

<a class="grade"> Text in an &lt;a&gt; element, which has the class grade itself. </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `typeTag.className` for target `a` element:

```css
li.grade {
    color: red;
}

li.grade a i {
    color: green;
}

a.grade {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
<li class="grade">
   <a><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i></a>
    My Text 
</li>
<a class="grade"> Text here should be white </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use style like below

```
a.grade {
  color : red;
}
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/e73t9mtk/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you never said what color you wanted the `i` to be, only that you didn't want it to be white. So I'll assume it should be the same color as the body. Write this.

```css
body, .grade i {
  color:#777;
}
```

Secondly, if you want not only the `a` elements inside a `.grade` white, but only the `a`s that have class `grade` themselves, you will have to add `a.grade` as a selector too.

```css
.grade a, a.grade {
  color: white;
}
```

So the complete code to do what you want is as follows.

```css
html {
  background:#ddd;
}

body, .grade i {
  color:#777;
}

.grade a, a.grade{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="grade">
     <a><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw">(icon goes here)</i></a>
       My Text 
  </li>
</ul>
<a class="grade"> Text here should be white </a>
```

(Note that I added a bit of text to the icon, to make it visible in the absence of FontAwesome.)